# argmax of a function involving summation of max functions

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, maxima-minima, differential

I am trying to calculate `argmax` of the following function w.r.t. $x$:

$$
f(x) = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{N} \Big( max (-||y_i - x||_2^2 + \alpha, 0)\Big)
$$

where $x$ and $y_i$ are vectors. I have tried to find the x* i.e the argmax by evaluating the derivative and setting it equal to 0, but no luck. I followed this approach:

$$
\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{N} \Big(2(y_i - x) \mathbf{1}(||y_i - x||_2^2 < \alpha)\Big)
$$
where $\mathbf{1}(.)$ is the indicator function. By putting the above equation equal to $0$, I should get the argmax, but the above equation seems tricky because of the indicator function.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to solve this problem as constrained optimization problem. You can consider the norm squared as the objective function and the constraint as the norm squared should be greater than $\alpha$.

Using KKT multipliers should be straight forward.

Comment: Thanks. I thought there might be a derivative way. But seems not so..